# Keyboard shorcut to zap/roam between different windows of the same application

Tags: 18.04, shortcut-keys

Let's say I have 2 chrome windows, 2 terminal windows and 1 file explorer window running.

I know it is funny to call those **windows**, but you got what I mean.

I am on Ubuntu 18.04, I can use `alt + tab` to change the active application, i.e, I can roam between chrome, terminal and file explorer.

However, I am not able to change between two chrome windows. While I was using MS Windows OS, I was able to do that.

I wonder if there is any method to do this on ubuntu.

I hope I made it clear.

Comment: @Terrance am I the only one who does not know which one is the *super* key? If you mean the key which has a windows logo on it, it does exactly the same thing with alt + tab

Comment: I haven't even heard the others than GNOME. But I did not do any changes, just a ubuntu18.04 installation.

Comment: @Terrance I forgot to mention you

Comment: @Terrance I saw that question after I posted this one actually. It is kind of solving the situation. However, I have to combine alt+tab with it so that I can roam between apps. I guess there is nothing more close to that one, though.

Comment: @Terrance see the problem is, on MS windows with just one key(key combination actually) hit(alt+tab) , you can go from matlab to chrome window1 and with the exact same key hit (alt+tab) you can go between chrome window1 and chrome window2. This is actually what I was looking for. And it is not possible with alt+backtick to roam between chrome window1 and matlab.

Comment: @Terrance I might not be express myself nicely in my question. Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: @Terrance I am kind of new at linux world, I think i should stick with the defaults.

Comment: I re-brought up my GNOME desktop and think I came up with an answer for you.  =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> you will notice a little down arrow below each app. If you continue to hold down <kbd>Alt</kbd> a window will appear below that with all open windows of the same app. While not letting <kbd>Alt</kbd> go, now press the <kbd>`</kbd> and it will cycle through all those windows of the same app. Without letting go of <kbd>Alt</kbd> you can now press <kbd>TAB</kbd> again to cycle back through open apps.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your efforts!